# What letter comes next in the sequence A, P, I, W, A, T

Tags: sequence, letter-sequence

What letter comes next in the sequence: A, P, I, W, A, T, ?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Is this a puzzle you created yourself? If no, please add a source (such as a link) - we have an attribution policy here, and unsourced posts will be closed.

Comment: If there is a correct answer, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark just beneath the voting arrows.  If it's not correct you can leave a comment below the answer.  thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The next letter is

> W

Because

> A Picture Is Worth A Thousand Words

Comment: Wow @SteveV. How in the world did you guess that? Kudos